# fgetcsv is not splition data properly

Tags: php, csv, reference, fgetcsv, addslashes

i am importing csv file to upload data into database. But in some products the description is not going through properly. 
the description is like

> TSD/UHC Model UG-132, 6\" gas revolver with plastic shells. Shells:
>   MUG131 & MUG131BRASS. 290-320 FPS with .20g BBS.
>
> **Legal
>   Disclaimer**
>
> **Restrictions:** You must be 18 or older to
>   order this product. In some areas, state and local laws further
>   restrict or prohibit the sale and possession of this product. In
>   ordering this product, you certify that you are at least 18 years old
>   and satisfy your jurisdiction\'s legal requirements to purchase this
>   product.
>
> **Warning:** This product may be mistaken for a
>   firearm by law enforcement officers or others, and altering its color
>   or brandishing the product in public may be considered a crime.

but when i print fgetcsv array it display this description in different array like.

> [2] => TSD/UHC Model UG-132, 6\" gas revolver with plastic shells.
>   Shells: MUG131 & MUG131BRASS. 290-320 FPS with .20g BBS. Legal
>   Disclaimer
>
> Restrictions: You must be 18 or older to order this product. In some
>   areas [3] =>  state and local laws further restrict or prohibit the
>   sale and possession of this product. In ordering this product [4] => 
>   you certify that you are at least 18 years old and satisfy your
>   jurisdiction\'s legal requirements to purchase this product.
>   Warning: This product may be mistaken for a firearm by law enforcement
>   officers or others [5] =>  and altering its color or brandishing the
>   product in public may be considered a crime.

"

I also have more products with this kind of description with backslash, single quot and double quot. some other products are uploaded properly but some are having problem.

Thanks

Comment: Show the fgetcsv() input line that you are using so we can see what enclosures and escapes you're using

Comment: i have mentioned text in question which i am parsing and also show that it splits into array so that i am facing problem in inserting data. String is too long so i cannot post it here so please refer it from question. it starts from "TSD/UHC Model UG-132, 6\" gas....." and ends with ".... public may be considered a crime.".  Thanks for quick response Mark...

Comment: Add some code! Specifically where `fgetcsv` is called

Comment: Please add that code line I've asked for; otherwise we can only guess that you're not correctly handling enclosures and escaped enclosures

Comment: i have tried fgetcsv($file, 1000, "\t") and fgetcsv($file) and fgetcsv($file, 1000, ","). but still result same

Comment: Unless the whole entry is wrapped in quotes, then it won't matter what you try as it will be a malformed csv file (or even simply a plaintext file

Answer (score 1):

`fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",", '"', '""');`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",", '"', '\\');
```

which use a comma (,) as a separator, unless it's part of a field wrapped in "; and if " appears as a character in the field it must be escaped with a \

If a comma isn't the separator, then you'll need to use the appropriate separator character

Comment: Thanks for help Mark..but it doesn't help...problem is still same

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and tried many different ways but without preprocessing and cleaning the whole file this was the only working solution:

```
$handle = fopen($filepath, "r");
if ($handle === false) {
    throw new someException('fopen error');
}

$rowNumber = 1;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '"', "\0")) !== false) {
    yield $rowNumber => $data;
    $rowNumber++;
}
fclose($handle);
```

I have found the working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342634/5356216

More details with code and example data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74721279/5356216