# Data gets garbled when writing to csv with fputcsv() / fgetcsv()

Tags: php, csv, escaping, fgetcsv, fputcsv

There seems to be an encoding issue or bug in PHP with fputcsv() and fgetcsv().

The following PHP code:

```
$row_before = ['A', json_encode(['a', '\\', 'b']), 'B'];

print "\nBEFORE:\n";
var_export($row_before);
print "\n";

$fh = fopen($file = 'php://temp', 'rb+');

fputcsv($fh, $row_before);

rewind($fh);

$row_after = fgetcsv($fh);

print "\nAFTER:\n";
var_export($row_after);
print "\n\n";

fclose($fh);
```

Gives me this output:

```
BEFORE:
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => '["a","\\\\","b"]',
  2 => 'B',
)

AFTER:
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => '["a","\\\\',
  2 => 'b""]"',
  3 => 'B',
)
```

So clearly, the data is damaged on the way. Originally there were just 3 cells in the row, afterwards there are 4 cells in the row. The middle cell is split thanks to the backslash that is also used as an escape character.

See also
https://3v4l.org/nc1oE
Or here, with explicit values for delimiter, enclosure, escape_char: https://3v4l.org/Svt7m

Is there any way I can sanitize / escape my data before writing to CSV, to guarantee that the data read from the file will be exactly the same?

Is CSV a fully reversible format?

EDIT: The goal would be a mechanism to properly write and read ANY data as csv, so that after one round trip the data is still the same.

EDIT: I realize that I do not really understand the $escape_char parameter. See also [fgetcsv/fputcsv $escape parameter fundamentally broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840256/fgetcsv-fputcsv-escape-parameter-fundamentally-broken) Maybe an answer to this would also bring us closer to a solution.

Comment: CSV has loads of limitations, from embedded quotes to multiline data.  This is why things like XML, JSON and various other formats are used.

Comment: I have plenty of embedded quotes and line breaks in data that I export to CSV, and until now there was never a (visible) problem.

Comment: CSV with line breaks in data isn't portable, if you just want data for your own application, why bother with CSV and just write any old format you want - and as your using all sorts of separators - you are effectively doing that.

Comment: 1. Depends on the application. E.g. LibreOffice Calc has no problem with it. It might be nonstandard, but the world does not care. 2. Because CSV (or PHP-flavoured CSV) is already supported natively, 3. I am using the standard separators mostly. The only reason I use different separators is to test if PHP will behave differently.

Comment: Also, the application I am developing has all sorts of CSV from external sources already, so I prefer to stick to this one format instead of inventing new formats.

Comment: @NigelRen I ended up writing my own userland CSV implementation that always replaces single enclosure characters in cells with double enclosure characters, and does not have a special "escape character". This seems to be bullet-proof. I processed a ton of data with it already, which all survives the round trip unaltered. I still use native fgetcsv() for csv files from external sources, since those often contain rogue single double quotes in cell contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit is that fputcsv() uses an escape character, which is a non-standard extension to CSV. (Well, as far as RFC 7111 can be regarded as standard.) Basically, this escape character would have to be disabled, but passing an empty string as $escape to fputcsv() doesn't work. Usually, passing a NUL character should give the desired results, however, see https://3v4l.org/MlluN.

Comment: Hey! I think my answer is more up to date at this point. But if you are the cmb who followed up on the bug report, and if cmb means you authored [this commit](https://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=3b0f05119383fe21ee75adaed3d0239ba8976aef), then all praise to you! I happily keep the checkbox on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE Jan 2020

Since PHP 7.4, passing an empty string as escape char fixes the problem!
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Demo https://3v4l.org/33Wja - see difference of PHP 7.4 vs older versions.
(this is the same snippet as below, just with empty string as escape char)

## Original answer

Contrary to what others are saying, I claim that this is a PHP bug. I am going to report it, and update this answer.

EDIT: Now reported here, https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74713

Discussed in this answer:

- Does changing the delimiter help? -> Not really.
- Could `fputcsv()` be fixed? -> Yes.

### Does changing the delimiter help?

It can be shown that this is reproducible with any combination of delimiter, enclosure and escape character.

https://3v4l.org/a29kR

```
$delimiter = 'X';
$enclosure = 'Y';
$escape_char = "Z";

$row_before = [
  'A',
  "[{$enclosure}a{$enclosure}{$delimiter}{$enclosure}{$escape_char}{$escape_char}{$enclosure}{$delimiter}{$enclosure}b{$enclosure}]",
  'B',
];

print "\nBEFORE:\n";
var_export($row_before);
print "\n";

$fh = fopen($file = 'php://temp', 'rb+');

fputcsv($fh,$row_before,$delimiter,$enclosure, $escape_char);

rewind($fh);

$row_plain = fread($fh, 1000);

print "\nPLAIN:\n";
var_export($row_plain);
print "\n";

rewind($fh);

$row_after = fgetcsv($fh, 500,$delimiter,$enclosure, $escape_char);

print "\nAFTER:\n";
var_export($row_after);
print "\n\n";

fclose($fh);
```

Output:

```
BEFORE:
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => '[YaYXYZZYXYbY]',
  2 => 'B',
)

PLAIN:
'AXY[YYaYYXYYZZYXYYbYY]YXB
'

AFTER:
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => '[YaYXYZZ',
  2 => 'bYY]Y',
  3 => 'B',
)
```

### Could fputcsv() be fixed?

For this let's turn back to more common and readable delimiter, enclosure and escape character.

```
$delimiter = ',';
$enclosure = '"';
$escape_char = "@";
```

Here the result is:

```
BEFORE:
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => '["a","@@","b"]',
  2 => 'B',
)

PLAIN:
'A,"[""a"",""@@",""b""]",B
'

AFTER:
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => '["a","@@',
  2 => 'b""]"',
  3 => 'B',
)
```

We see that the `'"@@"'` part is exported as `'""@@"'`, while it SHOULD have been exported as `'""@@""'`.

In fact, doing this manually with `fwrite()` instead of `fputcsv()` does fix the problem: https://3v4l.org/4U1CQ

Answer (score 0):

Using your code with specific delimiters but changing the following line will work...

```
$enclosure = "'";
```

I think it may be to do with thinking that the \ is escaping the following quote.

Comment: This does work for the given example. But one could simply craft another string to break it, like so: https://3v4l.org/LsTST

Comment: You can screw up any CSV export by putting a \n in the string, which is why my comment on the original post says that other formats are more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

As in php, `\\` used to escape the backslash([link for PHP manual escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)),so for making it as string u need to use one more single quote('  ').

so your input array should be...

```
$row_before = ['A', json_encode(['a', "'\\'", 'b']), 'B'];
```

Comment: But the goal is to process arbitrary incoming data. If I have to rewrite the input, I need an algorithm that always works..

Answer (score 0):

This is not PHP bug. It seems that `json_encode()` use the same delimiter (,), enclosure (") and escape (\) which is the same as default delimiter, enclosure and escape for both `fputcsv()` and `fgetcsv()`. You may differentiate enclosure or escape, and delimiter if necessary.

As already answered, in this case it will work by specify enclosure with (') instead:

```
$row_before = ['A', json_encode(['a', '\\', 'b']), 'B'];

print "\nBEFORE:\n";
var_export($row_before);
print "\n";

$fh = fopen($file = 'php://temp', 'rb+');

fputcsv($fh, $row_before, ',', "'");

rewind($fh);

$row_after = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ',', "'");

print "\nAFTER:\n";
var_export($row_after);
print "\n\n";

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Same as for Nigel's answer: It does work for the given example, but what if your array contains `"['a','\\\\','b']"`? Or more universally, `"[{$enclosure}a{$enclosure}{$delimiter}{$enclosure}{$escape_char}{$escape_char}{$enclosure}{$delimiter}{$enclosure}b{$enclosure}]"` or ``

Comment: You must not allow any (special) character that can cause bug.. You may try escape (") to Unicode Codepoint within json_encode(): `json_encode($value, JSON_HEX_QUOT);`. It will convert double quotes to `\u0022`.

Comment: Or use `strtr()` to make temporary replacement.. dirty and it's common